# Monitor vs Mutex in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between various threading synchronization options in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301160/what-are-the-differences-between-various-threading-synchronization-options-in-c)

What is the difference between a Monitor and a Mutex in C#?

When to use a Monitor and when to use a Mutex in C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301160/what-are-the-differences-between-various-threading-synchronization-options-in-c

Comment: I agree with using lock per default, but you need to call Monitor.Enter/Exit if 1) a timeout is needed or 2) if the locking scope is not restricted to a single method for some reason.

Comment: As an added note, Monitors provide what are often called "condition variables" with its Wait/Pulse methods. It allows one thread to wait for something until another thread call Pulse on the monitor.

Answer (score 53):

A `Monitor` is managed, and more lightweight - but is restricted to your `AppDomain`. A `Mutex` can be named, and can span processes (allowing some simple IPC scenarios between applications), and can be used in code that wants a wait-handle).

For most simple scenarios, `Monitor` (via `lock`) is fine.

Answer (score 25):

A good source of advice on this stuff is the "Threading in C#" by Joseph Albahari. All the content is available online. In my opinion, it's worth to read [the whole book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/threading.pdf), but yo can check these parts:

- On [Locking (C# Monitor)](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking);
- On [Mutex](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Mutex).

Although it does not cover [.NET 4.0 new parallel constructs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693%28VS.100%29.aspx), it's a very good starting point.

**Update**: The book has been updated. Now, it covers .NET 4.0 Parallel Programming in its [part 5](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx).

Answer (score 19):

A Mutex can be shared across processes, and is much more heavy-weight than a Monitor.

Use a Monitor unless you need to synchronize across process boundaries.