# C++ Mutex replacement in C sharp

Tags: c#, c++

I have a project which is written in C++ which has functionality of file copy and folder creations. It uses the `Mutex.Lock()` and `Mutex.unLock()` methods in C++.

I need to replicate the same in C#.

Please suggest which is the best way to write the C++ methods `mutext.Lock()` and `Mutex.unlock()` in C#?

Comment: There is a [Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx) class in c#

Comment: You are looking for the `lock` statement. Or for `Monitor.Enter/Exit`.

Comment: i would like to do what Mutex.Lock doesn in C ++..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ has no `Mutex` class. It has `std::mutex`, which provides `.lock()` and `.unlock()`.

So, in C++ you have,

```
std::mutex mtx;

void thr_fnc(){
    mtx.lock();
    // CS
    mtx.unlock();
}
```

To achieve same functionality in C#, you can do

```
Mutex mtx = new Mutex();

void thr_fnc(){
    mtx.WaitOne();
    // CS
    mtx.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `Mutex` in the normal case as it's more heavyweight than `Monitor` or the `lock` statement on an arbitrary lock object. See for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164038/monitor-vs-mutex-in-c-sharp

Comment: Hi ..In C sharp , mutext.Dispose is required ? does Realease mutex realease and disposes the thread?