# I don't understand difference between semaphore and lock

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, locking, semaphore

I do not understand some things.
For example binary Semaphore and lock are the same?
When using lock and when semaphore,or both?

Comment: Might be better suited for the Computer Science stack exchange. SO is more about specific programming questions, rather than theory and design practices.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/2332868/5656555

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between a lock and a binary semaphore is only a apparent when there are multiple processes trying to access the same resource.  A "process" is defined here as an instance of a program or application that may contain one or more threads.

Both allow only one thread to access a resource at a given time.  However, locks can only limit access within a **single** process while binary semaphores can limit access across **multiple** processes.

Therefore, within a **single process**, the behavior of a lock and a binary semaphore are the same.  Both allow only one thread to access a resource a given time.

Across **multiple processes**, the behavior is different.  A binary semaphore will allow only one process to access a given resource at a time, but a lock will give multiple processes to access to a resource a time (but only a single thread in each process will have access at a given time).