# Regarding `multiprocessing.Lock`, does Python use different terms for lock, mutex or semaphore?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, locking

To quote from an answer in [Lock, mutex, semaphore... what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332765/lock-mutex-semaphore-whats-the-difference)

> A lock allows only one thread to enter the part that's locked and the lock is not shared with any other processes.
>
> A mutex is the same as a lock but it can be system wide (shared by multiple processes).
>
> A semaphore does the same as a mutex but allows x number of threads to en

This is what I'm confused about: `multiprocessing` does fork/spawn new processes, right? So even though [`multiprocessing.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock) is called "lock", is it not really a lock but a mutex or semaphore?

Comment: Like you can read in documentation - `multiprocessing.Lock` works across multi processes and threads but traditional https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock works across threads within one process so indeed, `multiprocessing.Lock` works like mutex. This is only name convetion.

Comment: Also keep in mind, that multiprocessing was designed to resemble the threading API; accurate terminology might have been sacrificed for that design goal in some cases. That being said, I don't agree with the quoted definition that the threads synchronizing via a lock must belong to the same process.