# How to signal only one thread to wake up per event

Tags: c#, multithreading

## What I want to do

I want to create some threads, say thread A, B, C, and block them until an event occurs. When an event occurs, I want to release only one thread.

For Example:

```
Before event occurs:
Thread A : blocked
Thread B : blocked
Thread C : blocked

After event occurs:
Thread A : blocked
Thread B : unblocked
THread C : blocked
```

I read that `AutoResetEvent` can do this but I can't specify which thread to be unlocked, and `ManualResetEvent` will unblock all the blocked threads.

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: How do you determine which thread should become unblocked?

Comment: A thread that was popped from Ready queue will be the one that's going to be unblocked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create multiple instances of `ManualResetEvent`, one for each `Thread` and use `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne()` in each `Thread`, e.g.

```
public void StartThreadA()
{
    _mreA = new ManualResetEvent();
    _threadA = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => 
    {
        _mreA.WaitOne();
        // Continue
    });
}
```

When your even happens you can then handle it like so:

```
private void OnSomeEvent()
{
   _mreA.Set();
}
```

This is very limited in terms of scale, if you intend to use a large number of threads, I would suggest using a dictionary to look-up the `ManualResetEvent` for each thread.

**Update**

As I am now aware you are using a queue of threads I would do something like the following:

```
private Queue<ManualResetEvent> _queuedThreads = new Queue<ManualResetEvent>();

public void EnqueueThread()
{
    var mre = new ManualResetEvent();
    var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        mre.WaitOne();
        // Continue
    });

   _queuedThreads.Enqueue(mre);
}

private void OnEvent()
{
    var mre = _queuedThreads.Dequeue();
    mre.Set();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a Semaphore rather than a ManualResetEvent or AutoResetEvent.

There is a good basic example in the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also, here is a [related stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519/what-is-a-semaphore).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But in this particular problem, I had to suspend/resume threads without using the deprecated methods, locks, or semphores.

Comment: Unless you use a `Semaphore` or `SemaphoreSlim` per `Thread`, you will still lack control about which `Thread` to resume.