# How to lock 2 different methods of the same class in the same time?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have class:

```
public class petri {
    public int[] nodes = new int[3];
    public void petri (int n) {
        this.nodes[1] = n;
        this.nodes[2] = 0;
        this.nodes[3] = 0;
    }

    public bool start() {
        if (this.nodes[1] != 0) {
            this.nodes[1]--;
            this.nodes[2]++;
            return true;   
        } else
            return false;
    }

    public bool end() {
        if (this.nodes[2] != 0) {
            this.nodes[2]--;
            this.nodes[3]++;
            return true;   
        } else
            return false;
    }
}
```

I use this class from parallel threads and need to do so: start() **and** end() functuions must be used only by 1 thread in 1 time. I mean, if `thread1` call start(), `thread2` weit until `tread1` end performing start() and before this `thread2` can't call start() **and end()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an object field to your object to lock on and lock this object in each method you want to lock out together:

```
public class petri {
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public bool start() {
        lock(_lock)
        {
            // rest of method here
        }
    }

    public bool end() {
        lock(_lock)
        {
            // rest of method here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you require more than one lock, things become way more hairy, and you're going to have to deal with things like lock order and escalating locks (possibly).

Comment: Oh jeesh. Anyway i need only one lock, so thank you!

Comment: BTW This is likely to cause `start` to be run multiple times, followed by `end` multiple times.

Comment: @Aron Using `lock(...) {...}` won't do that, but not checking if already started will.

Comment: I mean if two threads are started to run `start` followed by `end`, then its likely the first thread would acquire the lock...run `start`...wait...the second thread would block on `start`. The first thread finishes `start` and unblocks `start` on the second thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use  Semaphore or synchronized method (Monitor)

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx

Comment: I'm using c#. Not Java.

Comment: Sorry... The same look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519/what-is-a-semaphore