# two semaphores not communicating

Tags: c, linux, locking, semaphore

I have a client server project using semaphores.
I run both from the same folder, and they use the same key.
Now, I want the server to lock the semaphore, so Client can't run commands until server frees it, but the client ignores the server's lock. I do not understand where my mistake is. Server code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#define FLAGS IPC_CREAT | 0644
union semun {
    int val;
    struct semid_ds *buf;
    ushort *array; };
union semun semarg;
struct sembuf sops[1];
int main() {
    semarg.val=1;
    int resultsCreator=open("results.txt",O_CREAT|O_RDWR);
    key_t key;
    key = ftok("results.txt", 'k');
    int shmid = shmget(key, 12, FLAGS);
    int semfor = semget(key, 1, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666);
    semctl ( semfor , 0 , SETVAL , semarg );
    sops->sem_num = 0;
    sops->sem_flg = 0;
    sops->sem_op = -1;
    int k = semop ( semfor , sops , 1 ); //lock the semaphore
    char* shmaddr;
    int numWaiting =0;
    while(1){   
        sleep(2); //CHECK EVERY 2 SECONDS IF SOMEONE IS WAITING
        numWaiting = semctl(semfor, 0, GETNCNT, semarg); 
        if(numWaiting==0){  
            printf("none waiting\n");
            continue; }
        printf("more than one waiter\n");  //NEVER GETS HERE
    } //END WHILE
```

Client code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#define FLAGS IPC_CREAT | 0644
union semun {
    int val;
    struct semid_ds *buf;
    ushort *array;
};   
union semun semarg;
struct sembuf sops[1];
int main()
{
    key_t key;
    key = ftok("results.txt", 'k');
    int shmid = shmget(key, 12, FLAGS);
    semarg.val=1;
    int semfor = semget(key, 0, 0666);
    semctl ( semfor , 0 , SETVAL , semarg );
    sops->sem_num = 0;
    sops->sem_flg = 0;
    sops->sem_op = -1;
    semop ( semfor , sops , 1 );
    printf("skipped lock\n"); //PRINTS IT, EVEN WHEN IT'S STILL LOCKED
    sops->sem_op = 1;
    semop ( semfor , sops , 1 );
    return 0;
}
```

why does the client ignore the server's semaphore lock?

Comment: Does the real code also miss any error checking?

Comment: /i deleted some non-important part to make it as short as possible, but my code has no errors, I showed here exactly what it prints

Comment: *i deleted some non-important part*  If you don't know why it's not working, you can't know what parts are non-important.  Print the return value of `semget()` - every time you run it.

Comment: I have this check for every system-call, and i deleted it since it never points to an error (never returns -1 )

Comment: leave all error checking in your code, have it only output a message to `stderr` when an error occurs.

Comment: the 'server' code:  1) is missing the header that defines `O_CREAT` and `O_RDWR`   The 'main()` function is missing one or more lines at the end.  3) there is code for `shared memory mapping`, but it is not done properly.

Comment: the `client` code: 1) there is code for shared memory mapping, but it is not done properly.

Comment: this line: `int semfor = semget(key, 0, 0666);`, because the second parameter is 0, will not create any semaphores.  Suggest changing that 0 to 1

Comment: regarding this line: `semctl ( semfor , 0 , SETVAL , semarg );`, if your machine is a linux box, then the `union semun` is missing a forth entry,  a `struct seminfo *_buf;`

Comment: normally, when discussing semaphores, the general names for the executables are `producer` and `consumer`.   How is that relating to the general names: `client` and `server`?

Comment: the array `sops[]`  when referenced in lines like: `sops->sem_num = 0;` should be written as: `sops[0]->sem_num = 0;`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the posted code for `server` is missing this line: `#include <fcntl.h>`

Comment: the `server` code is opening a file: `results.txt` for read/write, but never uses the resulting file descriptor.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99`)

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question to which I answered so I'll just copy it over here

If you're going to be technical, if you're syncing tasks between threads  you should use Semaphore. Example reading input before parsing it. 
[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519/what-is-a-semaphore) an answer on semaphores.

But if you're using shared resources, and need to avoid race condition/two threads accesing at the same time, you should use mutexes. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524/what-is-a-mutex) a question on what is a mutex.

Also look at the [disambiguation](http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/RTOS-Mutex-Semaphore) by Michael Barr which is a really good.

I would read both question thoroughly and the disambiguation, and you might actually end up not using semaphore and just mutexes since from what you explained you're only controlling a shared resource.

Common semaphore function

```
int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value); //Use pshared with 0, starts the semaphore with a given value

int sem_wait(sem_t *sem);//decreases the value of a semaphore, if it's in 0 it waits until it's increased

int sem_post(sem_t *sem);//increases the semaphore by 1

int sem_getvalue(sem_t *sem, int *valp);// returns in valp the value of the semaphore the returned int is error control

int sem_destroy(sem_t *sem);//destroys a semaphore created with sim_init
```

Common Mutexes functions (for unix)

```
int pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *p_mutex, const pthread_mutexattr_t *attr); //starts mutex pointed by p_mutex, use attr NULL for simple use

int pthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t *p_mutex); //locks the mutex

int pthread_mutex_unlock(pthread_mutex_t *p_mutex); //unlocks the mutex

int pthread_mutex_destroy(pthread_mutex_t *p_mutex);//destroys the mutex
```

I'm not sure why your code doesn't work but from what you're explaining you needn't use a semaphore, since there's no synchronization between the client and the server only the use of a shared resource. Try re-writing the semaphore part with a mutex, you'll see it will seem much more natural and will probably end up fixing the problem.