# POSIX Threads, unique execution

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

Is there a way to be sure only 1 thread executes a specific function?

```
for (i = startnotfirst; i < end; i++) {     

    gl_rand = (float) lrand48();

    fprintf(stderr, "\nTHREADING - #ID: %d - THIS IS MY RAND: %f", *mytid,rand);
    to_open = (rand / (float) INT_MAX) < (points->p[i].cost / z);
    if (to_open) {
        //printf("\nRANDOM: %f \nINT_MAX: %d \npointsDistance(cost): %f \nZ: %f \n\n RESULT: %f < %f\n\n\n",rand ,INT_MAX,points->p[1].cost , z,(rand / (float) INT_MAX),(points->p[i].cost / z));
        fprintf(stderr, "\nTHREADING - #ID: %d - im working...", *mytid);
        t_kcenter++;
        for (int k = start; k < end; k++) {
            float distance = dist(points->p[i], points->p[k], points->dim);
            //If distance is smaller add it to that cluster.
            float new_cost = distance * points->p[k].weight;
            if (new_cost < points->p[k].cost) {
                points->p[k].cost = new_cost;
                points->p[k].assign = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the gl_rand to be executed by only one thread and others know about the new rand value either by changing a `global variable` or `broadcasting`.

Also the threads must all have ended their job `iteration body`  before a new number comes out!

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Save the thread id of the thread that should generate the random number then call the random number generator only if the saved thread id matches the current thread id.

Comment: and how can i be sure that other threads wont surpass the random generator and execute the iteration body with the previous rand ? Also , any idea why this got downvoted ? O_O

Comment: You need explicit synchronisation. For example, a mutex to ensure only one thread accesses a global `gl_rand` and a barrier to ensure each thread operates in step.

Comment: @kaylum a mutex wont be enough , i think i need condition variables , but i can't find an example that helps me enough

Comment: Sure, that's what I meant by the barrier. Read the man pages and give it a try. We can't write the full solution for you but can help once you have tried and have a specific question related to that attempt.

Comment: Ah.  Your question is more complex than you thought.  What you want is some thread-safe mechanism to generate random numbers at specific times.  Thread-safe generators are pretty standard and an atomic compare-and-swap operation can do that.  A thread-safe way of controlling the generation of random numbers is more complex, and it's not possible to be more specific without knowing what conditions will trigger generating a new random number

Comment: @RayFischer i do understand it's a complex question :D No condition triggers the number generation , it's just an essential part of the iterations body and all threads must know the new one before they jump in.

Comment: @frcake I know exactly how to do this in C# but I don't know the details for Unix so, handwaving.  Create a counter that tracks how many threads have NOT fetched the current random number.  In an interlocked bit of code get the current random number, decrement the count and if it's zero then reset the count and generate a new random number.

Comment: I would consider separating the one function block into two, allowing you to set a "master thread" that runs an altered logic than the "slave" threads. This will also allow you to set a [semaphore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519/what-is-a-semaphore) that will help you sync the "master thread" with the "slave" threads... or you can spawn and join threads within the "master thread" loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `pthread_cond_wait()` and `pthread_cond_broadcast()`

In conjunction with [`pthread_mutex_lock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html)
[`pthread_mutex_unlock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_unlock.html), the
[`pthread_cond_wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html) and 
[`pthread_cond_broadcast()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html) functions are the key to achieving the required functionality.
However, considerable care is required to get the predicate right.

```
/*
** Objective: N threads cooperate on M cycles or iterations of a task.
** A new random number is needed for each cycle, but all threads must
** use the same random number on each cycle.
** Any thread may evaluate the new random number.
*/

#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "stderr.h"

#ifndef NUM_THREADS
#define NUM_THREADS 3
#endif
#ifndef NUM_CYCLES
#define NUM_CYCLES 5
#endif

enum { MAX_THREADS = NUM_THREADS };
enum { MAX_CYCLES  = NUM_CYCLES  };

static pthread_mutex_t mtx_waiting = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t  cnd_waiting = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static int             num_waiting = 0;
static int             cycle   = -1;

static float gl_rand = 0;
static long  gl_long = 0;

static float next_iteration_random_number(int tid, int iteration)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx_waiting);
    assert(cycle == iteration || cycle == iteration - 1);
    num_waiting++;
    printf("-->> TID %d, I = %d (C = %d, W = %d)\n",
           tid, iteration, cycle, num_waiting);
    while (cycle != iteration && num_waiting != MAX_THREADS)
    {
        assert(num_waiting > 0 && num_waiting <= MAX_THREADS);
        printf("-CW- TID %d, I = %d (C = %d, W = %d)\n",
               tid, iteration, cycle, num_waiting);
        pthread_cond_wait(&cnd_waiting, &mtx_waiting);
    }
    assert(cycle == iteration || num_waiting == MAX_THREADS);
    printf("---- TID %d, I = %d (C = %d, W = %d)\n",
           tid, iteration, cycle, num_waiting);

    if (cycle != iteration)
    {
        gl_long = lrand48();
        gl_rand = (float)gl_long;
        num_waiting = 0;
        cycle = iteration;
        printf("---- TID %d generates cycle %d: L = %ld, F = %g\n",
               tid, cycle, gl_long, gl_rand);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cnd_waiting);
    }

    printf("<<-- TID %d, I = %d (C = %d, W = %d) L = %ld, F = %g\n",
           tid, iteration, cycle, num_waiting, gl_long, gl_rand);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx_waiting);
    return gl_rand;
}

static void *thread_function(void *vp)
{
    int tid = (int)(uintptr_t)vp;     // Thuggish!

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CYCLES; i++)
    {
        float f = next_iteration_random_number(tid, i);
        printf("TID %d at work: I = %d, F = %g\n", tid, i, f);
        fflush(stdout);
        struct timespec rq;
        rq.tv_sec = 0;
        rq.tv_nsec = (((gl_long & 0xFF) + (0xF * tid))) % 200 * 50000000;
        assert(rq.tv_nsec >= 0 && rq.tv_nsec < 10000000000);
        nanosleep(&rq, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    assert(argc == 1);

    pthread_t thread[MAX_THREADS];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
    {
        int rc = pthread_create(&thread[i], 0, thread_function, (void *)(uintptr_t)i);
        if (rc != 0)
        {
            errno = rc;
            err_syserr("failed to create thread %d", i);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
    {
        void *vp;
        int rc = pthread_join(thread[i], &vp);
        if (rc != 0)
        {
            errno = rc;
            err_syserr("Failed to join TID %d", i);
        }
        printf("TID %d returned %p\n", i, vp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

<sup>*Source at [GitHub](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-4828-2480).  Library code in [`libsoq`](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq).  The routines starting `err_` are declared in header `stderr.h` and the supporting code is in `stderr.c`.  These greatly simplify error reporting.*</sup>

The `main()` function is trivial; it launches 5 threads, and then waits to join 5 threads.  The only tricky bit is relaying the thread number as an argument to the thread function.  The code converts the integer value into a `uintptr_t`, then coerces that to a `void *`; the called function undoes this sequence

The per-thread function is not complex.  It collects the thread number from its argument, then enters into a loop to iterate through the required number of cycles.  On each iteration, it passes the iteration number (and the thread number) to `next_iteration_random_number()`, which coordinates the random number generation.  The thread prints the data, then uses [`nanosleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html) to sleep for a not easily discernible amount of time that is under 1 second.

The interesting code is in `next_iteration_random_number()`.  First, the thread locks the mutex that controls the shared information. It then increments the number of waiting threads.  If the current cycle is not the same as iteration it is dealing with and the number of waiting threads is not equal to the total number of threads, then this thread calls `pthread_cond_wait()` to sleep until broadcast to.  When the thread gets out of the loop (either by waking up after a broadcast, or because it never entered the loop), the thread looks to see if the current cycle is the iteration it is expecting.  If not, it must be the last thread to try for this cycle — so it generates the random number and does the housekeeping to ensure that the other threads will know what is happening,
and then it uses `pthread_cond_broadcast()` to signal all the sleeping threads to awaken.  They can't actually wake yet; the current thread still holds the mutex.  It reports what it is doing and unlocks the mutex, and returns the random number.  The other threads detect that the cycle number is the same as the iteration they were waiting for, so they can each print the information, unlock the mutex, and return the number.

The key point is that each thread must know which iteration it is expecting to work on, and must sleep appropriately when that is not yet the current iteration.  There are assertions and printing operations aplenty in the code to help understand what's going on.

Wholly separately, since `lrand48()` returns a `long` (albeit with a value in the range [0,2<sup>31</sup>), so it is a 32-bit value even when `long` is a 64-bit type), which means there's a very good chance that it returns values which cannot be represented accurately in a `float`, so the `gl_rand = (float)lrand48();` code snipped from the question is dubious.  (The sample code also records the `long` value in `gl_long` and uses that on occasion.)

The code compiles cleanly on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.3 with GCC 6.3.0 and compilation options set to fussy:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -I../../inc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition pthrd37.c -o pthrd37 \
>     -L../../lib -lsoq 
$
```

#### Sample run

Program configured with 3 threads and 5 cycles:

```
-->> TID 0, I = 0 (C = -1, W = 1)
-CW- TID 0, I = 0 (C = -1, W = 1)
-->> TID 2, I = 0 (C = -1, W = 2)
-CW- TID 2, I = 0 (C = -1, W = 2)
-->> TID 1, I = 0 (C = -1, W = 3)
---- TID 1, I = 0 (C = -1, W = 3)
---- TID 1 generates cycle 0: L = 851401618, F = 8.51402e+08
<<-- TID 1, I = 0 (C = 0, W = 0) L = 851401618, F = 8.51402e+08
TID 1 at work: I = 0, F = 8.51402e+08
---- TID 0, I = 0 (C = 0, W = 0)
<<-- TID 0, I = 0 (C = 0, W = 0) L = 851401618, F = 8.51402e+08
TID 0 at work: I = 0, F = 8.51402e+08
---- TID 2, I = 0 (C = 0, W = 0)
<<-- TID 2, I = 0 (C = 0, W = 0) L = 851401618, F = 8.51402e+08
TID 2 at work: I = 0, F = 8.51402e+08
-->> TID 1, I = 1 (C = 0, W = 1)
-CW- TID 1, I = 1 (C = 0, W = 1)
-->> TID 0, I = 1 (C = 0, W = 2)
-CW- TID 0, I = 1 (C = 0, W = 2)
-->> TID 2, I = 1 (C = 0, W = 3)
---- TID 2, I = 1 (C = 0, W = 3)
---- TID 2 generates cycle 1: L = 1804928587, F = 1.80493e+09
<<-- TID 2, I = 1 (C = 1, W = 0) L = 1804928587, F = 1.80493e+09
TID 2 at work: I = 1, F = 1.80493e+09
---- TID 1, I = 1 (C = 1, W = 0)
<<-- TID 1, I = 1 (C = 1, W = 0) L = 1804928587, F = 1.80493e+09
TID 1 at work: I = 1, F = 1.80493e+09
---- TID 0, I = 1 (C = 1, W = 0)
<<-- TID 0, I = 1 (C = 1, W = 0) L = 1804928587, F = 1.80493e+09
TID 0 at work: I = 1, F = 1.80493e+09
-->> TID 2, I = 2 (C = 1, W = 1)
-CW- TID 2, I = 2 (C = 1, W = 1)
-->> TID 1, I = 2 (C = 1, W = 2)
-CW- TID 1, I = 2 (C = 1, W = 2)
-->> TID 0, I = 2 (C = 1, W = 3)
---- TID 0, I = 2 (C = 1, W = 3)
---- TID 0 generates cycle 2: L = 758783491, F = 7.58783e+08
<<-- TID 0, I = 2 (C = 2, W = 0) L = 758783491, F = 7.58783e+08
TID 0 at work: I = 2, F = 7.58783e+08
---- TID 2, I = 2 (C = 2, W = 0)
<<-- TID 2, I = 2 (C = 2, W = 0) L = 758783491, F = 7.58783e+08
TID 2 at work: I = 2, F = 7.58783e+08
---- TID 1, I = 2 (C = 2, W = 0)
<<-- TID 1, I = 2 (C = 2, W = 0) L = 758783491, F = 7.58783e+08
TID 1 at work: I = 2, F = 7.58783e+08
-->> TID 0, I = 3 (C = 2, W = 1)
-CW- TID 0, I = 3 (C = 2, W = 1)
-->> TID 2, I = 3 (C = 2, W = 2)
-CW- TID 2, I = 3 (C = 2, W = 2)
-->> TID 1, I = 3 (C = 2, W = 3)
---- TID 1, I = 3 (C = 2, W = 3)
---- TID 1 generates cycle 3: L = 959030623, F = 9.59031e+08
<<-- TID 1, I = 3 (C = 3, W = 0) L = 959030623, F = 9.59031e+08
TID 1 at work: I = 3, F = 9.59031e+08
-->> TID 1, I = 4 (C = 3, W = 1)
-CW- TID 1, I = 4 (C = 3, W = 1)
---- TID 0, I = 3 (C = 3, W = 1)
<<-- TID 0, I = 3 (C = 3, W = 1) L = 959030623, F = 9.59031e+08
TID 0 at work: I = 3, F = 9.59031e+08
---- TID 2, I = 3 (C = 3, W = 1)
<<-- TID 2, I = 3 (C = 3, W = 1) L = 959030623, F = 9.59031e+08
TID 2 at work: I = 3, F = 9.59031e+08
-->> TID 0, I = 4 (C = 3, W = 2)
-CW- TID 0, I = 4 (C = 3, W = 2)
-->> TID 2, I = 4 (C = 3, W = 3)
---- TID 2, I = 4 (C = 3, W = 3)
---- TID 2 generates cycle 4: L = 684387517, F = 6.84388e+08
<<-- TID 2, I = 4 (C = 4, W = 0) L = 684387517, F = 6.84388e+08
TID 2 at work: I = 4, F = 6.84388e+08
---- TID 1, I = 4 (C = 4, W = 0)
<<-- TID 1, I = 4 (C = 4, W = 0) L = 684387517, F = 6.84388e+08
TID 1 at work: I = 4, F = 6.84388e+08
---- TID 0, I = 4 (C = 4, W = 0)
<<-- TID 0, I = 4 (C = 4, W = 0) L = 684387517, F = 6.84388e+08
TID 0 at work: I = 4, F = 6.84388e+08
TID 0 returned 0x0
TID 1 returned 0x0
TID 2 returned 0x0
```

Notice that each thread happens to generate the random number at least once.  That's not something that can be guaranteed, but it shows that no one thread is privileged.

#### `pthread_once()`

A first version of this answer mentioned and illustrated the `pthread_once()` call.  This was not what was actually needed, but
it could be useful in other contexts.

Assuming you have a sufficiently POSIX-compliant system, if you want only one thread to do something, but it does not matter which thread does it, then I believe you're looking for [`pthread_once()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_once.html).

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static pthread_once_t once_only = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

static float gl_rand = 0;

static void pt_once(void)
{
    gl_rand = (float)lrand48();
}

void *thread_function(void *vp)
{
     pthread_once(&once_only, pt_once);
     …rest of the code…
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: will this happen once, in each iteration? and also when the other threads have ended the for loop ? cause if the rand changes in the middle of some calculation it'd be wrong. the sequence is: [SingleNumberGeneration]->[UpdateGlobal] -> [ReleaseThreads] -> [do_job(end of for)] -> [WaitForNewRand] . This is why im thinking about pthread_cond_wait and then broadcasting after the number generation . Also it's a ready code , i didn't write it , im just making it parallel from sequential! ill check what you told my about casting the float

Comment: It will happen once — period.  If you need once per iteration, then you have to coordinate the N threads so that they wait for all threads to be ready for the next iteration to start, then one process goes and runs the random number generator step, and then frees the other processes.  That's a different problem from the one I thought you were solving — but you should explain what you're up to with better code.

Comment: You're probably looking at [`pthread_cond_wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html),
[`pthread_cond_signal()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html),
[`pthread_cond_broadcast()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html) and related functions.  You'll need to think carefully about what you're up to.

Comment: Yes I'm closing in to something like this https://gist.github.com/frcake/e56ed3db546220080c402b9f8c4e0425 what do you think

Comment: The busy wait is a disaster.  But the germ of the idea might be right.  You should be thinking of calling a function, not writing the code inline.  It might be `float next_iteration_random_number(void);`, perhaps.  You'd need to set the wait queue back to zero before you broadcast.  Etc.

Comment: Note that if the number of iterations is not large (say, less than a million of them), it would be far simpler to have the main thread generate an array of random numbers, one per iteration, before it starts any of the threads, and then let the threads run free, reading the random numbers from the array as required.  This is fine unless the threads call `lrand48()` in their ordinary processing, or anything similarly ghastly.  If you don't know the number of iterations up front, or can't afford to preempt that much space, then this solution works (for me).  Upgraded code at GitHub.

Comment: Great answer!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: stupid question, but would it be correct (as another way of implementing) to put the execution of lrand() inside 2 barriers and execute only for id=X?

Comment: To the extent I understand what you're asking, I think the answer's no.  [IIUC](https://www.acronymfinder.com/IIUC.html), you're asking if it is OK to designate thread number X as the one that generates the random number, each time it wants to.  I think that's not correct — that process might be finished with cycle N before some of the others have started, and the others would therefore not necessarily see the correct value.  That said, if you wanted to complicate things, you could designate thread X to wait on condition 'generate new number', but  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ but you'd need the other threads to check that they're all ready before signalling the generate new number condition.  So, that seems like more complication for no real benefit, though I could imagine other scenarios where you would in fact need a single thread to generate the random number (because the single thread holds the seed material — I'm thinking of `erand48()`,  `jrand48()` or `nrand48()`, for example).  You might also need another condition 'random number has been generated' for the other threads to wait on and thread X to broadcast to.  Such fun.

Comment: I was just reading part of Chapter 7 "Real Code" in the book [Programming with POSIX Threads](http://www.informit.com/store/programming-with-posix-threads-9780201633924) by David Butenhof.  It describes and implements a 'barrier', which has pretty much the structure outlined in the solution here.  There's the mutex, the condition, a counter, a threshold, and a cycle number — all as devised for this answer.  Well, almost; the barrier counts down to zero instead of up to the threshold as this code does.  You can find the code (including the barrier code) at the linked site.