# does signal() and wait() do in a semaphor algorithm?

Tags: semaphore, pseudocode

Does signal() and wait() do in a semaphore algorithm?
I know that one of them does S++ and the other S-- but I am not sure which one does which. I have checked out the signal algorithm and it seems to show that signal brings the counter down to 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a semaphore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519/what-is-a-semaphore)

Answer (score 0):

**Conditional Variables** are the ones with `signal` and `wait`.

A Conditional variable is used when you want a thread to wait until a certain condition is met.

```
while(!canProceed) { cond.wait(); }
```

When another thread wants to unblock these blocked threads, it simply calls `signal` (to unblock one) or `broadcast` (to unblock all).

```
canProceed = true
cond.broadcast()
```

---

**Semaphores** are simply generalizations of a `mutex`. While a `mutex` allows for one thread inside a given critical section, `semaphores` allow for `N` threads inside.

Threads initially `wait` to enter a critical section; after they're done they `post` (at least using the `pthreads` API).

```
semaphore.wait();
do_stuff();
semaphore.post();
```